# Where does Android Studio show what `adb` is doing during launch?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm running Android Studio 3.5.3 (on a Mac) and have no trouble running my sample application e.g. via USB on a device.

I'd like to look a bit under the hood. I know how to use `adb` from the command line, but I would like to see how Android Studio invokes `adb`. However, the out put in the "Run" tool window for the application starts with

```
01/22 23:28:26: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-G903F.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.x.y/com.x.y.Example" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
```

Even when I make sure that the app is manually deinstalled first in the device, the "Install" task seems to run in the background and I can't find any trace of it.
Also the Event Log simply shows:

```
23:30   Gradle build finished in 271 ms
23:30   Install successfully finished in 6 s 447 ms.
```

In `idea.log`, outside of the IDE, I at least find:

```
2020-01-22 23:30:36,534 [thread 316]   INFO - ools.idea.run.tasks.DeployTask - Installing application: com.x.y 
2020-01-22 23:30:37,943 [thread 316]   INFO -            #com.android.ddmlib - Created install session 1216572273 with options -r -t -S 1321332 
2020-01-22 23:30:37,943 [thread 316]   INFO -            #com.android.ddmlib - Uploading APK /Users/vs/AndroidStudioProjects/.../app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk to session 1216572273
```

but also that is opaque. I'm pretty sure that earlier versions would show `adb install ...` in the Tool window.

Where do I find this part of the launch process, or which option needs to be enabled?

Comment: (Of course, `idea.log` might almost suggest that `adb` is no longer involved directly but some "session mechanism")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `install`-task seems to fall a bit between the cracks -- when launching an application via "Run", installation is done via Gradle, just like compilation, and (of course/obviously) done before the `adb shell am start`. The only way I could inspect the output of the install-phase is by invoking e.g. the `installDebug` target via IntelliJ's Gradle-UI. Only **then** will the Run tool window show the exact `adb` invocations.

In other words, the installation sequence is not shown in detail at all when selecting to "Run" the application (as Gradle output is only summarised in the Event Log).

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Run tab

And this text was added needlessly because there were not enough characters in the answer

Comment: As I wrote, the "Run" output starts with `adb shell am start`